# Django import-export import button throws mysterious TypeError

Tags: django, django-import-export

I've been trying to get django-import-export working with the admin page of my site, but have run into a brick wall.  Currently I'm working with an empty database (schema have been created from Models, but no data have been added).  The "export" button seems to work fine, but clicking the import button throws a TypeError which I can't decipher for the life of me.  Here it is:

```
    TypeError at /admin/new_bridge/wordtable/import/

__init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/new_bridge/wordtable/import/
Django Version:     1.8.3
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

__init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/import_export/admin.py in import_action, line 178
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/home/jack/ds/bridge-repo',
 '/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode',
 '/opt/new_bridge/']

Server time:    Fri, 17 Jul 2015 15:38:33 -0500
```

And here's the Traceback for that error:

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/new_bridge/wordtable/import/

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'new_bridge',
 'import_export')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/import_export/admin.py" in import_action
  178.         resource = self.get_import_resource_class()()

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/new_bridge/wordtable/import/
Exception Value: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

If it helps, I tried importing via `manage.py shell` (referencing [the docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html)), and it worked.  Here's what I did:

```
import tablib
from import_export import resources
from new_bridge.models import *
book_resource = resources.modelresource_factory(model=WordTable)()
dataset = tablib.Dataset(['1', 'title'], headers=['id','title'])
result = book_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)
print result.has_errors()
False
```

Here is the model in question (from models.py):

```
class WordTable(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(db_column='TITLE', max_length=17, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'word_table'
```

...and the relevant portions of manage.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources
from new_bridge.models import WordTable

class WordTableResource(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = WordTable
        fields = ('title')

class WordTableAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    fields = ['title']
    resource_class = WordTableResource
    pass

# Register models w admin to make them editable:
admin.site.register(WordTable, WordTableAdmin)
```

This has really thrown me through a loop.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your `WordTableResource` class is inheriting from `ImportExportModelAdmin` instead of `resources.ModelResource`.

Comment: (my apologies for the delay in my response; I just got back from vacation)

Thank you so much!  Worked a treat.